# Pumping lemma L={$a^i$ $b^j$, / 0<j<i<infinity}?

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

How to prove that above language is not regular. I tried using pumping lemma but am not able to prove and what to select as initial string. I also searched for other answers but this question is not discussed. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because pumping in the initial block of $a$ will not violate the definition of the language, EXCEPT for one case: let $p$ be the constant from the pumping lemma and take the string $a^pb^{p-1}$. The pumping takes place in the initial block of $a$, because $|xy|<=p$. Now note that the lemma says, that also $xy^0z$ must be in the language. In our case $y^0$ means the deletion of some letters $a$, and therefore the resulting word is not in $L$.

Alternatively, you could use the fact that the regular languages are closed under [reversal](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-to-show-that-a-reversed-regular-language-is-regular). It should be straight-forward to prove that $\{b^ja^i: 0<j<i \}$ is not regular via the pumping lemma.

Comment: Your idea is correct but there is little mistake . I am not able to edit properly. Please update it to a^p b^(p-1) as i>j,not i>=j. Thanks.

Comment: My edit is rejected. Don't know why. Hope you got what I am trying to convey.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for the little lapse.